# Equations of motion for $\mathcal{L}=\sqrt{\phi^*\phi}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism

Suppose the follow Lagrangian density:

$$
\mathcal{L}[x,t]=\sqrt{\phi[x,t]^*\phi[x,t]}
$$

The Euler-Lagrangian equations with respect to $t$ yields:

$$
\begin{align}
0&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\phi[x,t]^*\phi[x,t]}} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\phi[x,t]^*\phi[x,t])\right)\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\phi[x,t]^*\phi[x,t])
\end{align}
$$

Am I correct into thinking of the "equations of motions" as a probability conservation condition? If I integrate both sides, I recover the normalization condition.

---

Can I take the Euler-Lagrangian equations of both variables $x$ and $t$ as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
0&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\phi[x,t]^*\phi[x,t]}} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\phi[x,t]^*\phi[x,t]) +\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\phi[x,t]^*\phi[x,t])\right)\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\phi[x,t]^*\phi[x,t]) +\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\phi[x,t]^*\phi[x,t]) \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

What is the physical interpretation of this equation?

Comment: If you write down a completely random expression, how are we supposed to tell you what the physical interpretation is? Could you at least say a bit about what you had in mind?

Comment: In particular, you've asked about 20 questions on the theme of "what if I consider a Lagrangian with a square root in it?" but almost none of them really are answerable unless you sharpen the question.

Comment: @knzhou Well for this one the square root just vanishes into the 0 term, so in this case, the equations of motions are equivalent to those obtained from $\mathcal{L}=\phi^*\phi$

Comment: So what is the point of the square root?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay Yes, that's indeed what you showed, but since we don't know what your goal was we can't really answer this question. For example, do you really want to ask "when can I take the square root of a Lagrangian and have the equation of motion unchanged?" If so, that's a good question and you should ask that instead.

Comment: The Lagrangian has no kinetic terms, and the equations of motion are $\phi^* = \phi = 0$ classically.

Comment: @JamalS It could also be a constant, right, so $\phi^*=z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay No, the equations of motion fix both fields to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

There is no version of "Euler-Lagrangian equations with respect to t". You must use the "full" version, that is -
$$\partial_\mu\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}$$

In your case the LHS is identically zero, thus the EOM results in $\phi=\phi^*=0$